# python: How to remove punctuations from file

Tags: python, file-io, punctuation

I have an input file, each line of which is in the formar of a list in python. It looks something like this:

```
['people', 'desert', 'snow']
['people', 'flower', 'garden', 'goat']
```

I want to process this file and remove all the punctuations from it, i.e. "[", "]", "," and "'"

I am using the following code:

```
import string
import re

openfile=open('jcn','r')
writefile=open('jcnout','w')
punctuation=["[","]",",","'"]

for line in openfile:
    line.translate(None, string.punctuation)
    writefile.write(line)

writefile.flush()
writefile.close()
openfile.close()
```

But it doesnt seem to work, i.e. punctuation are retaind in the output file.
Could someone please tell me where i am wrong

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: note: `.close()` flushes the file; you can drop `writefile.flush()`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian  : Thanks, would keep that in mind from now on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
line.translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

to

```
line = line.translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

In Python, strings are immutable. Correspondingly, `translate()` doesn't change the string in place, but rather *returns* the translated string (which you're ignoring).

Answer (score 0):

To support punctuation *inside* the strings:

```
import ast
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1): #NOTE: replace inplace
    print " ".join(ast.literal_eval(line))
```